# How to get Windows user credentials using forms authentication?

Tags: c#

Our all libraries and application use forms authentication, so it is necessary to use it here.

The application is hosted on IIS with below settings:

anonymous authentication: enabled

forms authentication: enabled

windows authentication: disabled (this must not be changed)

This returns the user under IIS runs (in my case `IIS APPPOOL\tdm`)

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
string userName = Environment.UserName;
```

In web.config:

```
<authentication mode="None" /> //(this again must not be changed)
```

Is it possible somehow to take the Windows credentials of the user who uses the application?
My job is when someone enters the app to log in with this credentials automatically, but for that, I must find a way to take his Windows user account.

Comment: I see you've used `winforms` tag but you're saying that you application is hosted in IIS. Are you sure you've used the correct tag? Are you working on a winforms application or web application?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Web application is.

Comment: Just trying to understand more on your problem statement. Do you want the details of the Windows user who is currently logged in the machine?

Comment: Sorry again. I edited the post. Yes, that user i need, who is logged in the machine.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that what you are asking for is possible within a standard webforms framework. You cannot automatically get a browser to send the windows credentials without enabling windows authentication.

If the application is hosted on the same domain, it is relatively easy to use standard forms authentication with an existing AD username/password - also called Single Sign On.

When you enable Windows authentication in an application, and then make a request from a browser, it actually returns a [401 - Unauthorized](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2) status code. The browser then decides based on your settings whether to send your identity in a second request. This may happen automatically, or it may prompt for credentials.

Comment: Thank you, and with Kerberos will be impossible, I guess.